# Urllib2 not returning entire data

Tags: python, json, urllib2, icecast

I'm trying to download icecast json status data from a server using python.

This is my code (after different attempts).

```
def checkStream(url):
  request = urllib2.Request(url)
  request.add_header("Connection", "keep-alive")
  request.add_header("Cache-Control", "max-age=0")
  request.add_header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8")
  request.add_header("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
  request.add_header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36")
  request.add_header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch")

  response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
  line = response.read()
  print line
  return

checkStream("http://108.168.175.149:10128/status-json.xsl")
```

The problem is that my response is printed like this

```
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS, HEAD

{"icestats":{"admin":"icemaster@localhost","banned_IPs":0,"build":20141112090605,"host":"pro02.caster.fm","location":"Earth","outgoing_kbitrate":3799,"server_id":"Icecast 2.3.3-kh11","server_start":"05/Oct/2015:10:43:46 -0500","stream_kbytes_read":104422400,"stream_kbytes_sent":5123403693,"source":[{"audio_codecid":2,"audio_info":"ice-samplerate=44100;ice-bitrate=96;ice-channels=2","bitrate":96,"connected":33748,"genre":"Various","ice-bitrate":96,"ice-channels":2,"ice-samplerate":44100,"incoming_bitrate":95920,"listener_peak":153,"listeners":42,"listenurl":"http://pro02.caster.fm:10128/live","mpeg_channels":2,"mpeg_samplerate":44100,"outgoing_kbitrate":3883,"queue_size":358609,"se
```

The end of the json response is short 272 bytes which is exactly the number of bytes of the response headers which are returned in the data.

If I open the link on chrome the response appears ok.

I also tested using `requests` lib with no luck.

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get("http://108.168.175.149:10128/status-json.xsl")
>>> r.text
u'Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT\r\nCache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS, HEAD\r\n\r\n{"icestats":{"admin":"icemaster@localhost","banned_IPs":0,"build":20141112090605,"host":"pro02.caster.fm","location":"Earth","outgoing_kbitrate":3844,"server_id":"Icecast 2.3.3-kh11","server_start":"05/Oct/2015:10:43:46 -0500","stream_kbytes_read":104438630,"stream_kbytes_sent":5124109510,"source":[{"audio_codecid":2,"audio_info":"ice-samplerate=44100;ice-bitrate=96;ice-channels=2","bitrate":96,"connected":35133,"genre":"Various","ice-bitrate":96,"ice-channels":2,"ice-samplerate":44100,"incoming_bitrate":95920,"listener_peak":153,"listeners":43,"listenurl":"http://pro02.caster.fm:10128/live","mpeg_channels":2,"mpeg_samplerate":44100,"outgoing_kbitrate":3837,"queue_size":164258,"se'
>>>
```

How can I retrieve the complete data?

Comment: Did you use `requests`?

Comment: i tried with `requests` and there was no problem.

Comment: Content-length requesting thet URL on browser is 961 bytes. SUre request is not being chopped or your calculation being done over a chopped fragment?

Comment: I tried with requests, httplib and urllib2, none of them worked. I'm using python 2.7. Which version are you using?
There are no exceptions and if I try to read more times nothing is fetched. :/

Comment: On python 3.5.1 the requests lib is working, why this happens in my 2.7.10 version?

Answer (score 0):

The server you are requesting this from is running an ancient version of an Icecast fork.

This bug was fixed and the fix released long ago in mainline. I'd recommend to upgrade (or tell the operator to upgrade) the server to the latest official Icecast version from http://icecast.org

Comment: If it's an icecast bug why does with python 3.5.1 it works while not with 2.7.11?

Comment: I don't remember details, something about content-length being off. If that's not it, then it might really be a python bug.